# Returning multiple columns with subquery and 'where in'

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having some trouble getting a select query to return the data I need. See the simplified example below.

**Sku table**

```
Sku         SkuId
==================
ABC-123     123
DEF-456     456
GHI-789     789
JKL-987     987
```

**SkuCombo table**

```
SkuId       SkuComboId  Qty
===========================
123         456         1
123         789         2
123         987         1
```

A "combo" item is a sku number given to an item that consists of multiple items. For example, for the sku `ABC-123`, you would need to look up the `Sku` from the `Sku table` to get the `SkuId`(123), then use the `SkuId` to get the `SkuComboIds` (456, 789, 987) from the `SkuCombo`. Then use those on the `Sku` table to get he corresponding `Sku`. The following query almost gets me there, but I don't know how to get the `Qty` column from the `SkuCombo` table?:

```
select * 
from Skus 
where SkuId in (Select SkuComboId 
                from SkuCombo  sc
                join Skus s on s.SkuId = sc.SkuId
                where s.Sku = 'ABC-123')
```

**Desired result**

```
Sku         SkuId       Qty
============================
DEF-456     456         1
GHI-789     789         2
JKL-987     987         1
```

Comment: What's wrong with the single join queries you've got as answers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `SELF JOIN` :

```
select sk1.Sku , sk1.SkuId, skc.qty
from Sku sk inner join 
     SkuCombo skc
     on skc.SkuId = sk.SkuId inner join 
     Sku sk1
     on sk1.SkuId = skc.SkuComboId;
```

Comment: Dang it, I was very close to this in a previous attempt. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I'm oversimplifying, or don't understand your question 100%, but wouldn't an Inner Join be the answer here:

```
Select *
from Skus s
join SkuCombo sc on s.SkuId = sc.SkuComboId
```

Comment: This isn't restricting to the SKUs related to ABC-123?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily done using inner join as there are no null values in either of the table.

```
SELECT s.Sku, s.SkuId, sc.Qty
FROM SkuCombo sc
    INNER JOIN Skus s ON sc.SkuComboId = s.SkuId
```

Comment: This isn't restricting to the SKUs related to ABC-123? (Also, please don't write in all capitals....)